# javascript plugin to display calendar

Tags: javascript, typescript, calendar, material-design

I am trying to find a package that i could install that would just display a view of a calendar as follows

[image]

I dont need to add an event or anything i just solely want it for display purposes.
I currently use the fullcalendar.io for adding events.

I have tried to search online for a package but have not found any.
Does anyone know what i could use to achieve the above image calendar view?

Comment: Did you know that this is supported natively with [`<input type="date">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date)? But since you're using Material-UI, why not just use the [Calendar](https://material-ui-pickers.dev/api/Calendar) component? Or just Google for something else...

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but aren't you just looking for a simple image of a calendar?

Comment: @Lissy93 i have tried that but i need it to stay open on load not when you click into it

Comment: @deanpillow Added an example code as an answer. If either of the answers helped, you should accept one of them, to help future users find the solution their looking for.

Answer (score 1):

To just display a calendar, it should be quite a simple task, and no need for an external package.

What about something like this, inspired by [code-box calendar](https://code-boxx.com/simple-pure-javascript-calendar-events/#sec-download)

```js
// Start
_("#calendar").innerHTML = calendar();
 
// short querySelector
function _(s) {
  return document.querySelector(s);
}
 
// show info
function showInfo(event) {
  // link
  var url = "https://codepen.io/nakome/pen/EWBMzm.css";
  // get json
  getjson(url, function (obj) {
    for (var key in obj) {
      // if has envent add class
      if (_('[data-id="' + key + '"]')) {
        _('[data-id="' + key + '"]').classList.add("event");
      }
      if (event === key) {
        _("#calendar_data").classList.toggle("show_data");
        // template info
        var data =
          '<a href="#" class="hideEvent" ' +
          'onclick="return hideEvent();">&times;</a>' +
          "<h3>" +
          obj[key].type +
          "</h3>" +
          "<dl>" +
          "<dt><dfn>Title:</dfn></dt><dd>" +
          obj[key].title +
          "</dd>" +
          "<dt><dfn>Hour:</dfn></dt><dd>" +
          obj[key].time +
          "</dd>" +
          "<dt><dfn>Venue:</dfn></dt><dd>" +
          obj[key].venue +
          "</dd>" +
          "<dt><dfn>Location:</dfn></dt><dd>" +
          obj[key].location +
          "</dd>" +
          "<dt><dfn>Description:</dfn></dt><dd>" +
          obj[key].desc +
          "</dd>" +
          '<dt><dfn>More Info:</dfn></dt><dd><a href="' +
          obj[key].more +
          '" title="More info">Here</a></dd>' +
          "</dl>";
 
        return (_("#calendar_data").innerHTML = data);
      }
    }
  });
  return false;
}
// toggle event show or hide
function hideEvent() {
  _("#calendar_data").classList.toggle("show_data");
}
 
// simple calendar
function calendar() {
  // show info on init
  showInfo();
 
  // vars
  var day_of_week = new Array("Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"),
    month_of_year = new Array(
      "January",
      "February",
      "March",
      "April",
      "May",
      "June",
      "July",
      "August",
      "September",
      "October",
      "November",
      "December"
    ),
    Calendar = new Date(),
    year = Calendar.getYear(),
    month = Calendar.getMonth(),
    today = Calendar.getDate(),
    weekday = Calendar.getDay(),
    html = "";
 
  // start in 1 and this month
  Calendar.setDate(1);
  Calendar.setMonth(month);
 
  // template calendar
  html = "<table>";
  // head
  html += "<thead>";
  html +=
    '<tr class="head_cal"><th colspan="7">' +
    month_of_year[month] +
    "</th></tr>";
  html +=
    '<tr class="subhead_cal"><th colspan="7">' +
    Calendar.getFullYear() +
    "</th></tr>";
  html += '<tr class="week_cal">';
  for (index = 0; index < 7; index++) {
    if (weekday == index) {
      html += '<th class="week_event">' + day_of_week[index] + "</th>";
    } else {
      html += "<th>" + day_of_week[index] + "</th>";
    }
  }
  html += "</tr>";
  html += "</thead>";
 
  // body
  html += '<tbody class="days_cal">';
  html += "</tr>";
 
  // white zone
  for (index = 0; index < Calendar.getDay(); index++) {
    html += '<td class="white_cal"> </td>';
  }
 
  for (index = 0; index < 31; index++) {
    if (Calendar.getDate() > index) {
      week_day = Calendar.getDay();
 
      if (week_day === 0) {
        html += "</tr>";
      }
      if (week_day !== 7) {
        // this day
        var day = Calendar.getDate();
        var info =
          Calendar.getMonth() + 1 + "/" + day + "/" + Calendar.getFullYear();
 
        if (today === Calendar.getDate()) {
          html +=
            '<td><a class="today_cal" href="#" data-id="' +
            info +
            '" onclick="return showInfo(\'' +
            info +
            "')\">" +
            day +
            "</a></td>";
 
          showInfo(info);
        } else {
          html +=
            '<td><a href="#" data-id="' +
            info +
            '" onclick="return showInfo(\'' +
            info +
            "')\">" +
            day +
            "</a></td>";
        }
      }
 
      if (week_day == 7) {
        html += "</tr>";
      }
    }
 
    Calendar.setDate(Calendar.getDate() + 1);
  } // end for loop
  return html;
}
 
//   Get Json data
function getjson(url, callback) {
  var self = this,
    ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
  ajax.open("GET", url, true);
  ajax.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (ajax.readyState == 4) {
      if (ajax.status == 200) {
        var data = JSON.parse(ajax.responseText);
        return callback(data);
      } else {
        /* Handle click with `ajax.status` */
      }
    }
  };
  ajax.send();
}
```

```css
*,
*:after,
*:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
 
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background: #efefef;
}
/* for demo */
.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 320px;
  height: 480px;
  background: #fff;
  margin: 1em auto;
  border: 4px solid #e2e2e2;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 9px -6px #c5c5c5;
  border-top-width: 25px;
  border-bottom-width: 32px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
div#calendar {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #f3f3f3;
}
table {
  width: 100%;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0;
}
.head_cal {
  background: #fff;
  color: #85baff;
  font-size: 2rem;
  line-height: 5rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.subhead_cal {
  background: #85baff;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  line-height: 2rem;
}
.week_cal {
  background: #fff;
  color: #d7d7d7;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 2rem;
}
.white_cal {
  background: #ececec !important;
}
tbody.days_cal tr td a {
  padding: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #fff;
  color: #888;
  height: 3.2rem;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 3.2rem;
  display: block;
}
tbody.days_cal tr td {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px solid #ececec;
  text-align: center;
  width: 14.28571428571429%;
  height: auto;
}
.event {
  color: #85baff !important;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.today_cal.event {
  background: #ff8d8d !important;
  color: #fff !important;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.today_cal.event:hover,
.event:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.week_event {
  color: #85baff;
}
#calendar_data {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  color: #c5c5c5;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: scale(0, 0);
  transition: all 0.8s ease;
}
 
#calendar_data h3 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin: 0;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  color: #43aeef;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dfdfdf;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
#calendar_data dl {
  padding: 0.5em;
  margin-left: 0;
  display: block;
  height: calc(100% - 4rem);
}
#calendar_data dt {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  width: 5rem;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue",
    Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #43b0ef;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0.2rem;
}
#calendar_data dd {
  margin: 0 0 1rem 5rem;
  padding: 0 0.5rem 0.5rem 0.5rem;
  font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue",
    Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  line-height: 1.2rem;
  color: #adadad;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eaeaea;
}
#calendar_data dd:last-child {
  border: none;
}
 
#calendar_data a:not(.hideEvent) {
  color: #43aeef;
  border: 0.1rem solid #43aeef;
  padding: 0.2rem 1rem;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.show_data {
  opacity: 1 !important;
  visibility: visible !important;
  transform: scale(1, 1) !important;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
 
.hideEvent {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  line-height: 2rem;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  border-left: 0.1rem solid #e5e5e5;
  color: #d3d3d3 !important;
}
.hideEvent:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #f55;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="calendar"></div>
  <div id="calendar_data"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont know if this would help anyone but i used the pikaday plugin to achieve this.

[pikaday](https://github.com/Pikaday/Pikaday)

and i set the following so it would always be open

html

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker" style="display:none;">
```

ts

```
async datePicker() {
    
        var field = document.getElementById('datepicker');
        var initiateDateCalendar = field as HTMLElement;
        initiateDateCalendar.click();

        var picker = new Pikaday({
            field: field,
            format: "D MMM YYYY",
            bound: false,
            container: document.getElementById('container'),
            
        });     

    
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).